# Android Fused Location provider gets lost

Tags: android, gps, location

I've been testing android's new Location API's for a few weeks. In general they work quite well, however, the new Location provider frequently loses the plot.

Specifically, I wire up an example based on [the receive location updates example](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). It works correctly, and the location updates are received as expected.

The problem seems to be with the Fused provider itself. In some areas (notably around my home) it completely gets lost. It will suddenly think I am kilometers away from where I am. Around where I work (which is a more built up area) it is much more accurate and always reasonably close to where I actually am (in Balanced mode).

I have made many attempts to fix this, including switching to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY when I suspect it is in error, or using the older LocationManager to try get a GPS fix to establish where I really am. But nothing seems to help too much. I suspect Google has bad data on where certain mobile towers of WiFi hotspots are around my home, and when it connects to certain towers is suddenly jumps a few km from the true location. It's very annoying and will interfere with the Geofence API also. Any advice on how I can fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by switching to the old LocationManager and GPS doesn't help much?

Comment: Sorry, I was not notified of your comment. There is another LocationManager in a different namespace: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: Oh, and yes, GPS always solves the problem. It seems that the incorrect locations are related to bad readings from surrounding cell towers.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66160

Answer (score 1):

Can you just ignore the location updates that are inaccurate? This code was released at Google IO 2013 I think, so it might still have some bugs.

(I am experiencing the same thing as you. Rural area, the Fused Location provider is giving me locations all over the place)

Comment: Hi,

Unfortunately, no I can't. It reports high accuracy. So for example, it'll tell me it is 11m accurate but it's actually off by 1.5km. Then suddenly it comes right again. Right now I just need to double-check all its results. I'm just hoping they improve it as time goes on. It's also much more accurate in heavily built up areas. I think perhaps the mobile tower info in some locations around here is just out-dated.

Comment: Just for the future; I had actually forgot to grant my application the "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission. The Fused Location Provider still works but will only give inaccurate locations.

Comment: Yeah no, I definitely have fine and coarse location. A lot of the time, fused location provider is kind of amazing in accuracy, without touching the GPS. I find this especially true in the city, where GPS sometimes gets confused anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is bad data about some WIFI APs from time to time, and these tend to fix themselves after a while.  A clue to what's happening to you can be found in the accuracy returned.  If when it goes to the wrong place, the accuracy is a large number (hundreds of meters), that implies the fused location provider is using a cell location.  It may mean there aren't a lot of APs where you live, and that you can only get a wifi location once in a while (or once in a while you can't get a wifi location).  The FLP should get better at avoiding these jumps over time as algorithms improve.

If the bad location you get has a small accuracy (around 30 meters), that implies it's a wifi location, and bad AP database information probably explains the issue.